# Creating packages in Python: package has no access to classes

Tags: python, pypi

I have problems when creating packages in Python.

My source file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='myPackage', 
version='1.0',
zip_safe=False,  
packages=['myRFMpackage'])
```

My actual function is in calculateSth.py:

```
def calculateSth(data):
    return(1+1)
```

My `__init__.py` is:

```
from .calculateSth import calculateSth
```

When I unpack the generated source distribution and try to run

```
import myPackage 
myPackage.calculateSth(data)
```

I get the error:
"module 'myRFMpackage' has no attribute 'calculateRFM'"

Can anybody help?

Edit: My directory structure is:

myRFMpackage

- setup.py
- myRFMpackage

  1. *init*.py
  2. calculateRFM.py

Comment: please also describe the directory structure of your project

Comment: Where is `calculateRFM` mentioned in your code?